# Measuring processing time in R and then accessing it through a variable

Tags: r, time

I am a beginner and I would like to measure time of a spatial process and input it in a variable. Is there a way to do that with R. I have tried using `library(tictoc)` but I think the measurements are inaccurate when inputting them in a variable, because my time is 2 secs and using the `toc()` function I get the value 8320.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `microbenchmark` package is pretty good if you just want to measure time for simple expressions. It is measuring time units much smaller than seconds and it will give you a data frame of times.

For example

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> (bench <- microbenchmark(mean(1:100), sum(1:100)/length(1:100)))
Unit: microseconds
                     expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max
              mean(1:100) 3.771 3.9225 4.49793  4.013 4.1515 40.636
 sum(1:100)/length(1:100) 1.023 1.1380 1.43525  1.217 1.3280 18.373
 neval
   100
   100
```

will give you `bench` which is a data frame

```
> class(bench)
[1] "microbenchmark" "data.frame"
```

It contains the time measurements for all the runs. Use `bench$expr` to get the expression that was measured -- in this example the `mean(1:100)` or `sum(1:100)/length(1:100)` expression -- and `bench$time` gives you the time.

Comment: You can also plot the bench to get an in-time breakdown of the process.

Comment: @Quant18 what I am going for is plotting the time of a process for every 100 values in a data frame which has 1000 values

Comment: Can I do that or multiple values? Because I need to test a classification algorithm for multiple values with microbenchmark.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by multiple values, but you can call `microbenchmark` with as many arguments as you like. If you mean calling it at different times during the algorithm, you have to do a little more work, because then you have to merge the results, but I think `rbind` should work with that... not sure how it handles if the time units differ, though.